# MongoDB Aggregate add a new field to docs where if an another field already exists

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Sample of my collection :

```
[
  {
    _id: "5e13asdfasuh",
    animal: "dog",
    gender: "male",
    age: 5,
    name: "mark",
    breed: "gold"
  },
  {
    _id: "5e13asdfasuhss",
    animal: "dog",
    name: "snow",
    age: "2",
    breed: "husky"
  }
]
```

Which ever docs has **gender** column need to add a field with value `gender_count:1`

**Output :**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e13asdfasuh",
    "age": 5,
    "animal": "dog",
    "breed": "gold",
    "gender": "male",
    "gender_count": 1,
    "name": "mark"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e13asdfasuhss",
    "age": "2",
    "animal": "dog",
    "breed": "husky",
    "name": "snow"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your sample documents and the expected output don't fit well. The second document has also gender field, but in the expected output it doesn't have `gender_count:1`. Also why do you have two age field in one document. And it would be good to post your sample documents and the expected output in json format like this: `{
    "_id": "5e13asdfasuh",
    "animal": "dog",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 5,
    "name": "mark",
    "breed": "gold"
  }`

Comment: My bad. Edited the question.

Comment: Can you also edit the first document so that it doesn't have multiple age fields?

Comment: did that too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            gender_count: {
                /** Check field 'gender' exists,
                 *  So if gender field doesn't exists then condition becomes false (As we're returning false),
                 *  ultimately as we're using '$$REMOVE' then gender_count will not be added to that doc */
                $cond: [
                    {
                        "$ifNull": [
                            "$gender",
                            false
                        ]
                    },
                    1,
                    "$$REMOVE"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9F9pmGZKFJ6)

Comment: more easier: `$cond: ["$gender", 1,"$$REMOVE"]`

Comment: @Valijon : Yes it might be or might not be helpful here, but in general when it evaluates on a field which has falsey values then condition can go wrong which may be misleading while you're checking for a field to exist..